# Find largest integer k that renders the inequality true.

Tags: inequality

$\frac{3}{2} \times \frac{2}{1} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{3}{4} \ldots \times \frac{k}{k+1} \ge \frac{1}{8}$

What I've tried so far:

$\frac{36}{48} \times \frac{k}{k+1} > \frac{1}{8}$

divide $\frac{1}{8}$ by $\frac{36}{48}$,

get $\frac{k}{k+1} = \frac{1/8}{36/48}$

then try solving for $k$...?

Would seriously appreciate some help here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the first four fractions all cancel out. So now we have:
$$
\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{k-1}{k}\right)\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right) \geq \frac{1}{8}
$$
But observe that all but two of the numbers in the fractions in the LHS cancel in pairs (the $4$'s cancel, the $5$'s cancel, ..., the $(k-1)$'s cancel, and the $k$'s cancel). This leaves us with:
\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{k+1} &\geq \frac{1}{8} \\
24 &\geq k+1 \\
k &\leq 23
\end{align*}

Comment: Not sure what you mean by (k - 1)'s cancel. There's only 1 (k - 1).

Comment: Do you agree that the $5$'s cancel?

Comment: Hmm, not seeing it...

Comment: Pretend that $k = 7$. Then all but the $3$ and $k + 1 = 8$ cancel out:
$$
\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) \left(\frac{5}{6}\right) \left(\frac{6}{7}\right) \left(\frac{7}{8}\right) = \frac{3}{8}
$$
Likewise, if $k = 8$, then all but the $3$ and $k + 1 = 9$ cancel out:
$$
\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) \left(\frac{5}{6}\right) \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)\left(\frac{8}{9}\right) = \frac{3}{9}
$$
This pattern continues for any integer $k \geq 4$ that you pick. If you're still not convinced, then we could always prove it by induction.

Comment: I kind of see it now. And in that case, we would need to find 3 over a certain denominator, which gives a fraction that reduces to 1/8, that being 3/24, right?

Comment: I still don't really understand your process where you achieve 23 as an answer...

Comment: As you said, we know that the last fraction must have a denominator of $24$. But since $(k+1)$ will always be the denominator of the last fraction, we know that $k$ should be $23$ so that adding one gives us a denominator of $k + 1 = 24$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16522/discussion-between-user164403-and-adriano).